# Limit templates available when creating sub site?

Tags: site-definition

I have created a site definition but i need to limit what sub sites can be created by the user.

How can I do this with SharePoint 2010?

thanks

Comment: We are not using the publishing feature.  How can we limit the list of templates that are listed for creating sub sites?

Answer (score 4):

As part of the publishing features you can add AvailableWebTemplates and AvailablePageLayouts declaratively as feature properties in onet.xml:

```
<Feature ID="22A9EF51-737B-4ff2-9346-694633FE4416">    <!-- Publishing -->    <Properties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
...
<Property Key="AvailableWebTemplates" Value="*-BLANKINTERNET#1;*-BLANKINTERNET#2"/>
<Property Key="AvailablePageLayouts" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleLeft.aspx:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleLinks.aspx:~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/ArticleRight.aspx"/>
...
</Properties>
</Feature>
```

The * can be replaced with a specific LCID (eg 1033) if you only want the template available for specific languages. Seperator is ; for templates and : for page layouts

Comment: Can this be done without turning on the publishing features?

Comment: SPWeb.SetAvailableWebTemplates() is what you are looking for. Filter on LCID to only allow templates for specific languages. Also remember to call update on SPweb after setting the allowed templates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms435526.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know if there is a declarative way to do it. But you can have a feature activtaed which receives following event whenever a new web is being created. You will have an opportunity to check for allowed templates and then redirect the users to error page if needed.

public override void WebAdding(SPWebEventProperties properties)
{
// Check properties.Web.WebTemplate belongs to the allowed templates... and if not do following

properties.Cancel = true;
properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithRedirectUrl;
properties.RedirectUrl = "/_layouts/Custom/error.aspx";
}